# Border-radius is clipping my image which is inside a div. Overflow visible isn't working

Tags: css, wordpress, overflow, border, clipping

My Header icons get clipped ONLY when border-radius is set (around 45% and above). Simply removing border-radius fixes the clipping, but then the circle border becomes a square.

I've messed around with overflow, position, span, etc. but I honestly don't know what I'm doing and nothing works.

```
.navbar .second-menu img {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    object-fit: contain;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 5px;
}

.navbar .second-menu img {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.500s!important;
    transition: all 0.500s!important;
}

<div class="second-menu">

<a href="/my-account" data-toggle="tooltip" data-title="Account"><img class="wow bounceIn" data-wow-delay="1.5s" src="https://www.punibunni.com/wp-content/themes/punibunni/images/top-members.jpg" alt="" style="visibility: visible; animation-delay: 1.5s; animation-name: bounceIn;"></a>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you increase the padding? Are you using `box-sizing: border-box;`?

Comment: Can you explain what's happening, I can't see any differences between the before and after images...

Comment: I've increased padding to no avail and yes, I'm using box-sizing: border-box

Comment: Of course! Sorry about that. The clipping is almost non-existent, but it's definitely there on the rabbit ears and ever so slightly on the Bag icon (lower left).

Comment: Or `display: inline-block`

Comment: I think it might just be a case of increasing the size of the artboard of the actual images, do you have access to the editable files?

Comment: Removing the padding just enlarges the icons and displays "real" clipping. I took screenshots

Comment: if the height and width are 50px and the padding is say 10px, then try the border-radius at 30px (60 / 2), instead of using percentages...

Comment: Editable files? Do you mean via Wordpress or my FTP?

Comment: No I mean editing the actual graphics so that there is more white space around them. Else you could try wrapping your images in another element, like a `span` tag and applying the padding and border to that instead.

Comment: Both sound like great ideas. I will try the wrapping.

Comment: Good luck, make sure you're setting `display: inline-block;`